# Pechkin with Windows Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, pechkin, tuespechkin

I'm getting this error whenever I try to debug the Azure project from Visual Studio. I checked on my original site project file the Platform Target and project's and every dependence as well are using "Any CPU". Not really sure what to do from here.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Pechkin' or one of its dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you running 32 bit allowed? Lots of docs out there talk about this being a limitation. 
mark as the answer please if that is the problem. There are solutions as well. apparently a guy did a fork called tuesPechkin with 64 bit versions.

Comment: in IIS > AppPool > your AppPool > Advanced > Enable 32 bit support

Comment: Enabling 32-bit support or using TuesPechkin is correct. :)

Comment: so wait, do i just remove pechikin and use tuespechkin instead?

Comment: He has quite a bit of support. If you follow his fork he updates and went through a huge azure issue for another guy. His implementation is different however so make sure you read his docs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get wkhtmltopdf working on Azure. See [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/eb48e701-8c0b-4be3-b694-2e11cc6ff2e1/wkhtmltopdf-in-windows-azure?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) and [this Gitgub issue](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin/issues/3).

> I am assuming you mean running wkhtmltopdf on Windows Azure Websites.
>
> wkhtmltopdf uses Window's GDI APIs which currently don't work on Azure
>   Websites.

A solution could be to create a Windows service (or for example a web api endpoint), which runs the Tuespechkin converter. Then create a VM in Azure and install the Windows service/end point there.

Comment: What would you suggest using instead?

Comment: Hi, this is not a solution nor workaround. Its simply a suggestion for alternatives

Comment: What are you expecting? The answer to this question is that using (Tues)pechkin in Azure does not work because of GDI limitations. For those running everything in Azure a solution is to use an Azure-hosted Windows machine which holds the PDF generation code.

Comment: Expecting a work around when you say you posted a link to it. That aside, what I need is some way of converting html to pdf on a website hosted in azure. So something that doesnt user GDI probably. Do you know of any solution to this?

Comment: The "solution" answer's the OP's question (how to get pechkin working in Azure), not yours. You could create your own question, but it would be off-topic for StackOverflow. Anyway, iTextSharp might work for you, but that's not free. I don't know any others which are not based on wkhtmltopdf.