# Using tuespechkin with MVC project in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, tuespechkin

I can't manage to get pechkin or tuespechkin to work on my azure site.

Whenever I try to access the site it just hangs with no error message (even with customErrors off). Is there any further setup I'm missing? Everything works perfectly locally.

For a 64 bit app I'm completing the following steps:

- Create a new Empty MVC App with Azure, make sure Host in the cloud is selected
- Change the app to 64 bit
- Log onto the azure portal and upgrade the app to basic hosting and change it to 64 bit
- Install the TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win64 and TuesPechkin nuget packages
- Add a singleton class to return the IConverter

  ```
  public class TuesPechkinConverter
  {
  private static IConverter converter;

  public static IConverter Converter
  {
      get
      {
          if (converter == null)
          {
              converter =
          new ThreadSafeConverter(
              new PdfToolset(
                  new Win64EmbeddedDeployment(
                      new TempFolderDeployment())));
          }

          return converter;
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- Add a Home controller with the following code in the Index Action:

  ```
  var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
      {
          GlobalSettings =
          {
              ProduceOutline = true,
              DocumentTitle = "Pretty Websites",
              PaperSize = PaperKind.A4, // Implicit conversion to PechkinPaperSize
              Margins =
              {
                  All = 1.375,
                  Unit = Unit.Centimeters
              }
          },
          Objects = 
          {
             new ObjectSettings { HtmlText = "<h1>Pretty Websites</h1><p>This might take a bit to convert!</p>" },
             new ObjectSettings { PageUrl = "www.google.com" }    
      }
      };

      byte[] pdfBuf = TuesPechkinConverter.Converter.Convert(document);
      return File(pdfBuf, "application/pdf", "DownloadName.pdf");
  ```

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood, but I don't think TuesPechkin actually works on Azure Websites (as per the github page) https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin. The reason is that the library uses GDI which isn't available under azure.

Comment: Ah, I spotted that now - I may need to use a 3rd party conversion service then :( started investigating it as it was mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059144/pechkin-with-windows-azure

Comment: Are there any other quick and easy to use alternatives that can convert HTML > PDF on Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, you can't make it work in a **web app**. However, there is a way you can do it: you have to create a **cloud service** and add a worker role to it. **TuesPechkin** will be installed in this worker role.

The workflow would be the following: from your cloud web app, you would access the worker role(this thing is possible by configuring the worker role to host Asp.NET Web API 2). The worker role would configure a converter using **TuesPechkin** and would generate the PDF. We would wrap the pdf in the web api response and send it back. Now, let's do it...

To add a cloud service (suppose you have Azure SDK installed), go to **Visual Studio** -> right click your solution -> **Add new project** -> select **Cloud** node -> **Azure Cloud Service** -> after you click **OK** select **Worker Role** and click **OK**.

Your cloud service and your worker role are created. Next thing to do is to configure your **Worker Role** so it can host **ASP.NET Web API 2**. 
This configuration is pretty straightforward, by following [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-an-azure-worker-role) tutorial.

After you have configured your **Worker Role** to host a web api, you will have to install the TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win64 and TuesPechkin nuget packages.

Your configuration should now be ready. Now create a controller, in which we will generate the PDF: add a new class in your **Worker Role** which will extend `ApiController`:

```
public class PdfController : ApiController
{
}
```

Add an action to our controller, which will return an `HttpResponseMessage` object.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GeneratePDF(PdfViewModel viewModel)
{
}
```

Here we will configure two `ObjectSettings` and `GlobalSettings` objects which will be applied to an `HtmlToPdfDocument` object. 
You now have two options.

You can generate the pdf from html text(maybe you sent the html of your page in the request) **or** directly by page url.

```
var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
{
    GlobalSettings =
    {
        ProduceOutline = true,
        DocumentTitle = "Pretty Websites",
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4, // Implicit conversion to PechkinPaperSize
        Margins =
        {
            All = 1.375,
            Unit = Unit.Centimeters
        }
    },
    Objects = {
        new ObjectSettings { HtmlText = "<h1>Pretty Websites</h1><p>This might take a bit to convert!</p>" },
        new ObjectSettings { PageUrl = "www.google.com" }
    }
};
```

A nice thing to now is that when using page url, you can use the `ObjectSettings` object to post parameters:

```
var obj = new ObjectSettings();
obj.LoadSettings.PostItems.Add
    (
        new PostItem() 
        {
            Name = "paramName",
            Value = paramValue
        }
    );
```

Also, from **TuesPechkin** documentation the converter should be thread safe and should be kept somewhere static, or as a singleton instance:

```
IConverter converter =
    new ThreadSafeConverter(
         new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>(
              new Win64EmbeddedDeployment(
                   new TempFolderDeployment())));
```

Finally you wrap the pdf in the response content, set the response content type to *application/pdf* and add the *content-disposition* header and that's it:

```
byte[] result = converter.Convert(document);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result);

response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
response.Content.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myFile.pdf");
return response;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is that it's not possible to get wkhtmltopdf working on Azure.

[See this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/eb48e701-8c0b-4be3-b694-2e11cc6ff2e1/wkhtmltopdf-in-windows-azure?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

> I am assuming you mean running wkhtmltopdf on Windows Azure Websites.
>
> wkhtmltopdf uses Window's GDI APIs which currently don't work on Azure
>   Websites.

[Tuespechkin supported usage](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin#supported-usage)

- It supports .NET 2.0+, 32 and 64-bit processes, and IIS-hosted applications.
- Azure Websites does not currently support the use of wkhtmltopdf.

**Workaround**

I ended up creating a Azure Cloud Service, that runs wkhtmltopdf.exe. I send the html to the service, and get a byte[] in return.